# Underclocking GPU <-> Overclocking GPU

Tags: gpu, nvidia-graphics-card, overclocking

I have the following situation: A NVidia GTX 260, in P0 State the power supply can't give enough power so we decided to let it in P8 state. But now we want a bit more performance from the P8 state. We could achieve this by underclocking the P0 state or by overclocking the P8 state.

I can modify the GPU-Clock, Memory-Clock, Shader-Clock but not the Voltage.

So the question is what's better and how risky is it regarding physical damage to the card.

Settings for P0: GPU-Clock: 625 MHz Memory-Clock: 1100 MHz Shader-Clock: 1348 MHz Voltage: 1.120 V

Settings for P8: GPU-Clock: 400 MHz Memory-Clock: 250 MHz Shader-Clock: 799 MHz Voltage: 1.050 V

I thought adjusting it to: GPU-Clock: 500 MHz Memory-Clock: 800 MHz Shader-Clock: 1100 MHz

Used program: NVIDIA Inspector 1.9.7.3

The main question is what's better overclock frequency with lower voltage, or underclock frequency with higher voltage, i want to achieve something between P0 and P8 values without harming the physical hardware.

Comment: Umm... get a proper power supply?

Comment: how did you decide your problem was limitation of power supply?

Answer (score 1):

Higher frequencies in digital hardware require higher voltage for stable operation. For this reason it's safer to underclock P0, since lower frequency is guaranteed to work with high voltage.

Overclocking P8 can lead to crashes (potentially damaging the hardware), you also risk to have rare, hard to reproduce errors when only a particular sequence of operations leads to a failure.

On the other hand, overclocking P8 will consume less power (similar current and lower voltage), so you have more chances that your power supply will provide enough power.